# Boolean Predicate (guard) in Java Optional

Tags: haskell, java-8, option-type

Here's the method I have.

```java
public PsiReference[] getReferencesByElement(@NotNull PsiElement element, @NotNull ProcessingContext context) {
    if (isInRoutesFile(element)) {
        return controllerName(element)
                .flatMap(name -> findController(element.getProject(), name))
                .map(controller -> new PsiReference[]{new RPsiElementReference(controller)})
                .orElse(new PsiReference[0]);
    }

    return new PsiReference[0];
}
```

Now, I'd like to avoid the `if` clause and somehow built the predicate into the `Optional` chain in order to not duplicate `new PsiReference[0]`.

For comparison, Haskell has a function `guard` for exactly that purpose. Here's how it would look like;

```haskell
references :: Element -> Maybe [Reference]
references element = do
    guard $ isInRoutesFile element
    controllerName element >>= findController (getProject element) >>= Just . return . Reference
```

This code will return `Nothing`, which is equivalent to `Optional.empty()` in case `isInRoutesFile element` is `False`. What's the Java way to have a guard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's `filter`.

```
return Optional.of(element)
         .filter(this::isInRoutesFile)
         .flatMap(this::controllerName)
         .flatMap(name -> findController(element.getProjcet(), name))
         ...;
```

Comment: The reference syntax is `this::isInRoutesFile`.